# How to use absolute url in aspx page on development machine?

Tags: asp.net, absolute-path, resolveurl

I find myself using the ResolveUrl function a lot in my aspx pages but the resolved path is always relative. i would like to be able to have the rendered path start with the regular "http://localhost/myproject/"

How can i achieve that without breaking any code in case i change the hierarchy of my files?
Would it be inefficient to write a function and call it for every targeted link on the page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind guys,
I found some code online from a Rick Strahl [post](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/154812.aspx) and it seems to be something i might use in my case!
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `~` when you resolve the url. It will always go to the application root.

Example

`~/somedirectory/default.aspx`

will resolve to...

`{applicationRoot}/somedirectory/default.aspx`

You will need to manually add the server address:

`Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port`

A sample function would be

```
string ResolveAbsoluteUrl(string path)
{
    return Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + ResolveUrl(path);
}
```

Comment: ok, but is there a function to get the 'http://localhost ..' part added to it too?